# how to select an area with magic wand like and flood fill it using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, flood-fill

i have scanned papers and their has black areas around the image caused by scanner.

i want paint them white in **openCV** c++.

i think i should select them and flood-fill them because i know [0 0] is in that area.

how can i do that?

i'v tried **cvblobslib_OpenCV_v8_3** and **OpenCV 2.2** but it doesn't work because of version mismath between them i presume.

here is part of my code:

```
cv::threshold(morphed,morphedbw,128,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
CBlobResult blobs;
IplImage xmorhped=morphedbw;
blobs = CBlobResult(&xmorhped , &xmorhped, 0 );
CBlob myblob=blobs.GetBlob(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     cv::floodFill(image, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(255.0,255.0,255.0));
```

fills the image with white color, starting from points (x,y).